# Application loader is waiting and network connection was lost

Tags: app-store-connect, itunes, application-loader

When I click the send button for sending my app in Application Loader, it is waiting for a response (sent API usage to iTunes Connect, waiting for response) and waiting without error. I am getting a message "the network connection was lost" after a couple minutes. I tried another network connection but the issue was not resolved. Could the issue be on iTunes network?

Comment: I'm seeing the same. It's probably a temporary itunes connect outage.

Comment: yes you are right. the problem resolved after 3, 4 hours. issue was itunes connection network

Comment: after trying to submit the app with organizer got timout, then try to use application loader and also got timeout I realize apple servers are tired a little.

Answer (score 21):

It should *just work* if you quit Application Loader, then re-open it.

Answer (score 3):

To submit an application to iTunes Connect, your Mac always need to be up to date, or you will be able to get errors. To do this click on Apple's logo > Software Update. I was having the same problem, and it solved for me. Cheers =)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your iTunes Connect user has admin privileges. I had it set at Technician and everything looked like it was working but it would hang on the "Sending API Usage to iTunes".

Answer (score 0):

I had to force quit and the re-open to make it work.

A normal restart did not work, nor did a restart of my Mac. Very weird.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above suggestions work for me. Likely the real cause is physical and related how Application Loader is using the internet. I have ADSL connection with a Netgear modem/router assigning each device at home a fixed IP address according to the mac address of the network interface of each device. I had noticed that when Application Loader is uploading, my Windows PC could not connect to the internet. However, if in Mac mini I use Safari doing various things like watching video, my Windows PC can access internet.

Even stranger, when Application Loader is uploading, the modem/router could easily lost connection to the internet, as I could see from the LED lights of the modem. The connection is lost randomly at any progress of uploading the 20 MB file.

So I had turned off Windows PCs, iPads, iPhones and Android device at home, so Mac mini is the only device using the Internet, the Application Loading has finally been able to upload the app successfully in one go.

My guess is, my home phone line has some noise, and Application Loader is using the internet aggressively particularly the up link, so stressing out the modem, then causing other devices like my Windows PC lost connection, not even able to resolve host.

So my working solution is to make Mac be the only device using the Internet, given that the internet connection is already in poor condition with noise, near the edge of losing connection.